# Is it possible to specify the max amount of time to wait for code to run?

Tags: python, timeout

I have a section of code that I need to get the output from:

```
gps = get_gps_data()
```

Though if it takes too long to get the output from `get_gps_data()`, I would like to cancel the process and set `gps` to `None`. Modifying the function is impossible, so is there a way to specify the max amount of time to wait for some code to run and abort if it reaches that time, say 5 seconds?

Comment: I think an important term you've left out of your searches is "timeout". I can't vouch for this library, but it provides a decorator to specify timeouts, which seems ideal to me: https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do some thing like below. This will work for any logic or function that you want to check and stop after some time. The function that you want to check and cancel is executed in a separate thread and monitored. After waiting for 3 seconds, it is cancelled.

Just put your code inside the `test` function (you can rename the functions). `test` function tries to sleep for 100 seconds (could be any logic). But the main call `future.result(3)`, waits only for 3 seconds else TimeoutError is thrown and some other logic follows.

```
import time
import concurrent.futures as futures


def test():
    print('Sleeping for 100 seconds')
    time.sleep(100)
    # Add your code here
    # gps = get_gps_data()
    return 'Done'


# Main
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(test)
    try:
        resp = future.result(3)
    except futures.TimeoutError:
        print('Some other resp')
    else:
        print(resp)
    executor._threads.clear()
    futures.thread._threads_queues.clear()
```

You can try to minimise the wait time inside the `test` function to some value less than 3 seconds. In this case, the original result returned from `test` function will be used.

Comment: Came up with a simpler solution for my specific use case, but that worked perfectly. Thanks! Will definitely add this to my repertoire for future projects.